# is there a way to lock a mutex only if a var is true to help dealing with a concept of atomicity?

Tags: c++, transactions, c++20, mutex, atomic

Is there a way to lock a mutex only if a variable as a specific value?

e.g.

```
class M
{
std::mutex m;

public:

void f1()
{
   std::lock_guard l(m);
   // do stuff...
}

void f2()
{
   std::lock_guard l(m);
   // do stuff...
}

void f()
{
// but here f wants to performs a "transaction on f1 and f2"
// so basically calling f1 and f2 in that defined way won't be enough.
   // mutex.lock();
   f1();
   f2();
   // mutex.unlock();
}
```

One solution would be to use a `recursive mutex`  for that, but i am trying to avoid them.

The other only way is to create for each public method a protected/private method without the locking to be used for composition in all the public ones, but in a class with only public members create each one private it looks like just a lot of work for so little...

A third one is to use `unique_lock` as it can be assinged to a variable, but again i don't really like it:

```
auto l = transaction ? std::unique_lock() : std::unique_lock(mutex)
```

Is there nothing in C++20 to help dealing with a concept of atomic transactions to avoid the `recursive_mutex` or writing a lot of "boiler plate code" derived from all the public methods ?

Or any other idea that could be used?

Comment: Isn't this what a recursive mutex *is*? This is kind of the bread-and-butter justification for why you would want to use one, right? More specifically, do you think what you would write instead would be faster?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `std::recursive_mutex`? This is a prime use case for it, and it would elegantly solve your problem. You could of course use an extra `std::atomic_bool` guard variable, but that seems redundant.

Comment: You're gonna have to work hard to beat `recursive_mutex` unless you have extra, game-changing information about your actual problem that you're leaving out of the question.

Comment: Reminder: if you want to lock multiple separate things that each have their own locks, pick a consistent order for taking locks, such as in order of increasing address.  That way you avoid deadlocks when thread 1 want to lock A and B, thread 2 wants to lock B and C, and thread 3 wants to lock C and A.

Comment: @PeterCordes The C++ standard library has [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) for that, so one doesn't have to implement the deadlock avoidance manually and also has exception safety automatically.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. Yes the recursive mutex just solve the problem elegantly without any extra hustles. 
Why i am trying to avoid it, it is mostly because i am searching if there is something better/alternative eventually. My goal was trying to find a way to use a normal mutex and an atomic to track also the state of the class and i think with a recursive mutex i don't really know how many times the mutex has been locked.

About performances/overhead is there any consideration on it?

Comment: Are `f1` and `f2` typically small enough to inline into the caller that wants to do them both as a transaction?  If so, that's relevant for efficiency considerations, e.g. you might use a template param to make them take a lock or not.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: you expose methods with keys.  The key here is a `lock_guard` (you can make it fancier to prevent lock picking).  People can call the bare `f1` and it locks the mutex, or they can pass in their own lock:

```
class M
{
  std::mutex m;

public:

  void f1(std::lock_guard const& l) {
     // do stuff...
  }
  void f1() {
    return f1(std::lock_guard(m));
  }

  void f2(std::lock_guard const& l) {
    // do stuff
  |    
  void f2() {
    return f2(std::lock_guard(m));
  }
};
```

but I find this to be a bad idea.

Instead I tend to do this:

```
template<class T>
struct mutex_guarded {
  template<class F>
  auto read( F f ) const {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write( F f ) {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }
private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  auto lock() const { return std::lock_guard(m); }
  T t;
};
```

now I can move the locking logic outside of the class.

```
mutex_guarded<M> bob;
bob.write([&](auto&& bob){ bob.f1(); });
bob.write([&](auto&& bob){ bob.f2(); });
bob.write([&](auto&& bob){
  bob.f1(); 
  bob.f2();
});
```

barring doing something rude, like passing a pointer or reference to a raw `M` out of the `.write` method, this guarantees that operations on `M` are within a mutex lock.

Generally in a non-buggy multithreaded program, there should be very few objects accessed from more than one thread.  The overhead of this pattern should be low enough for those few instances.

It can be extended to support n-ary access as well, for things like assignment or copy.  But if you are doing that it is unlikely your program will remain bug-free.

(My actual `mutex_guarded` is an alias of `lock_guarded<T, Mutex, template<class...>class ReadLock, template<class...>class WriteLock>`, allowing for easy substitution of reader-writer locks, recursive locks, or not locked versions.)

...

Note that we can also support

```
(bob->*f1)();
```

or

```
bob->*[&](auto&& bob){ bob.f1(); };
```

but after trying it, I advise against it.  The terseness you gain you lose in clarity.